# android toast a Chinese message to user

Tags: android

Basically I need to toast a message written in Chinese to user.
However I don't know how to achieve such thing.
Any solution that can help me?

Comment: Toast? I'm guessing there's a translation error here.

Comment: Nope, Toast is correct. See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: oh! sorry about that. since I normally use Toast class to output the message to user so I sometimes mess them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an Android programmer, but doesn't this work?

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "中国的网页";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Code ripped from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

(Apologies if that means anything offensive. I simply ripped some random characters from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/test/adding-some-random-chinese-characters.html)).

Comment: Yes, it can solve the problem "perhaps". But sometimes Eclipse or some IDE doesn't recognize Chinese character!

Comment: @Silver: if your IDE doesn't recognize the characters, then it's very most likely because the file your editing isn't encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: If Eclipse is giving you trouble, make sure your files are properly encoded in a Unicode format. *Edit* - Ninja'd.

Comment: +1 to Spencer's comment. To be clear: **UTF-8** is the encoding you want.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer. It's so simple I didn't think of that in the first place. And it always works.
Under res/values/string.xml of Android project, I edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="sample">中国的网页</string>
</resources>
```

And the I retrieve the string name "sample" out of project's resource using:

```
this.getString(R.string.sample);
```

Comment: You might want to check out how to add strings properly by e.g. looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions . In your case you should add this to the file strings.xml in res/values-zh unless you want your application to be chinese by default..