# Should my Android app default to simplified or traditional Chinese?

Tags: android, localization, cjk

I'm writing a localized Android app; I'm confused about how to handle the differences between simplified and traditional Chinese.

Thanks to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions) I know that I should put simplified Chinese in `values-zh-rCN` and traditional Chinese in `values-zh-rTW`.

But I should presumably put *something* in `values-zh`, right? Folks in Hong Kong and Macao shouldn't just get my default (English) strings.

My question is: is it better to put traditional Chinese in `values-zh`? Or should I make simplified Chinese the default? (Or should I just omit the `values-zh` directory?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditional Chinese characters (Standard characters) are referred to by several different names within the Chinese-speaking world. The government of Taiwan officially calls traditional Chinese characters standard characters or orthodox characters (traditional Chinese; simplified Chinese.

People in China, Malaysia and Singapore mainly use the simplified system, Traditional Chinese characters are currently used in Taiwan (Republic of China), Hong Kong and Macau.

I think that you should not omit that `values-zh` , put it as simplified Chinese or allow user to switch the language in your apps.

Comment: So how should strings be set up for an Android app?

Comment: See this guide http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html#localize_strings

Answer (score 1):

Android by default assumes `zh` to be Traditional by default, but Unicode (of which sets the standard for locale usage) uses Simplified for `zh`.

If your app's minimum version is Android 7.0 (API 24), then you can utilise the new locale resolution. By defining the folders as `values-b+zh+Hans` (Standard) and `values-b+zh+Hant` (Traditional), the system will automatically use the correct locale depending on which region was selected. You can still use `values-zh-rTW` and the like, if you need regional differences between the regions using the same variant.

Comment: if you can only choose ONE for your app, would you recommend one? I read simplified has many applications to turn it into traditional, but the vice versa is not true?

Comment: @KevinDanikowski On Android, since `zh` is set to be Traditional, I would recommend using `zh` for Traditional and `b+zh+Hans` for Standard.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my app which currently uses zh-rCN and zh-rTW only which cause issues for all other regions. Unfortunately based on this question ([Simplified and Traditional Chinese vs Regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions)), there's no actual way to determine which is best between those:

```
values-zh (traditional)
values-zh-rCN (simplified)
```

Or LOL

```
values-zh (simplified)
values-zh-rTW (traditional)
```

So I've been looking at the following alternative:

In my app I have a method that runs at the beginning to set the user-defined language, and if not actually defined I can check the current language/region and apply a patch accordingly while only keeping the zh-rCN and zh-rTW folders:

```
zh-rHK => zh-RTW
zh-rSG => zh-rCN
zh-rMO => zh-r?? can be both according to the link above
```

The method I use is partially described here: [Changing locale: Force activity to reload resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644377/changing-locale-force-activity-to-reload-resources/11941440#11941440)

EDIT: I've now made values-zh contain Simplified and patched the HK region to use Traditional automatically.