# Is there any need to prepare values-zh and values-zh-rHK

Tags: android, internationalization

In Android market console, Google only provides 2 type Chinese language : **zh-CN and zh-TW.**

Hence, besides preparing values-zh-rCN and values-zh-rTW, is there any need to prepare `values-zh` and `values-zh-rHK`, to ensure it works well in Nexus and Non-nexus devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to add values-zh and/or values-zh-rHK as Android offers only two variations *[citation needed]* of Chinese in Settings > Language & input > Language: **zh_CN** and **zh_TW**. So, there is no way for users to set the system locale to other Chinese locale than these. But...

But if you want to provide users in Hong Kong with custom values, you may consider using  values-zh-mccXXX so that the system may use R values from that folder if users mobile operator's MCC falls to that category.

Comment: Have you gone through this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions?rq=1 What we worry is those custom rom, which can be found many in Chinese market.

Comment: No, I have no first hand experience with Chinese locales. However, as you must have already seen from the conclusion of the accepted answer you have linked: _So to recap .. the minimum setup would be mirroring what is done in the settings app (only have zh-rCN and zh-rTW), but if you want to provide for default locales for Singapore, HongKong, Macau supplying traditional chinese as default you can do that too and it should work. I have however no evidence that such a configuration is used anywhere.._ --- **That's pretty much what I am saying**

Comment: I would say that `zh-rHK` **is needed**. Most OEM Android devices in Hong Kong have the language/region setting for zh-HK (at least for Sony and Samsung. It is very annoying for Hong Kong users to see Simplified Chinese in Apps even the App actually have Traditional Chinese strings. (I am one of these users.) @CheokYanCheng

Comment: Since Android 7.0, the options are **Simplified:** `CH, MO, HK, SG` and **Traditional:** `TW, HK, MO` – If it can't find the specific version the user has selected, it will default to `zh-rCH` for Simplified and `zh-rHK` for Traditional.