# Traditional and Simplified Chinese languages not being picked up separately

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources

I am trying to pick up languages for my app. I have **Traditional and Simplified Chinese** as languages too. All other languages are working but in case of Chinese, where I have 2 values folders, named **zh-rCN and zh-rTW**, its not taking the languages. Where as if I rename any folder to just **zh**, it will start picking up that folder string. Also when I rename the folders to **zh-CN** and **zh-TW**, that is showing **Error in res folder (AAPT Problem)**.? 
What can be done to show both languages separately.?

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me, make sure that

1. the strings are in *values-zh-rCN* and *values-zh-rTW* respectively
2. test on different devices to make sure it's just not a problem for a single device

Comment: Are there any other names for folders we can give in case of Traditional and Simplified Chinese.?

Comment: @Akshat you can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions