# How to add Traditional Chinese in Translations Editor of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Had tried looking over several times but still can't find Traditional Chinese or `zh-tw` in "Add Locale" list.

It's hard to believe because this list contains a huge amount of locales, including even the locale that might not be used by anyone like "Zhuang; Chuang".

Is there a way using Android Studio to add translations of Traditional Chinese?

Answer (score 1):

Open "src\main\res" directory of your project in the explorer/finder, you will see the folder "value-zh" if you added Chinese in Android studio.

Simply make a copy and rename them to:
                 "values-zh-rCN"   for simplified Chinese
             and "values-zh-rTW"   for all traditional Chinese

And android studio will automatically recognise that:

[image: Image - Android studio adapted]

See this as an example: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/res/

See more from this answer: [Simplified and Traditional Chinese vs Regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions)