# The Simplified Chinese language of my Android App is not displayed

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, resources

I have a problem with my android application and it is that I have translated it into Simplified Chinese and the translation is not displayed in the emulator (configured in the simplified Chinese language). I have another application that I have also translated and perfectly displays the translation in the same emulator. The emulator uses the x86 image 7.1.1 Google APIs and language settings is shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Settings Language Emulator]

I am developing it in Android Studio and I have tried to clean the project, to rebuild it, etc. and there is no way. The strings.xml file is in the *values-zh-rCN* directory according to the official android documentation and is as follows:

```
<resources>
    <string name="title_activity_search">搜索</string>
    <string name="title_activity_favorite">收藏</string>
    <string name="title_activity_topgpus">当前趋势</string>
    <string name="title_activity_compare">对比</string>
    <string name="title_activity_history">显卡浏览历史</string>
    <string name="title_activity_settings">设置</string>
    <string name="title_activity_about">关于</string>
    <!-- Productos -->
    <string name="amd_radeon">Radeon 系列</string>
    <string name="amd_firepro">FirePro 专业系列</string>
    <string name="nvidia_geforce">GeForce 系列</string>
    <string name="nvidia_quadro">Quadro 专业系列</string>
    <string name="nvidia_tegra">Tegra 系列</string>
    <string name="nvidia_nvs">NVS 专业系列</string>
    <string name="nvidia_tesla">Tesla 服务器系列</string>
    <string name="intel_desktop">Intel 桌面系列</string>
    <string name="intel_mobile">Intel 移动系列</string>
    <string name="intel_workstation">Intel 工作站系列</string>
    <string name="console_gpus">游戏机系列</string>
    <!-- Categorias AMD -->
    <string name="amd_rDesktop">Radeon 桌面端</string>
    <string name="amd_rLaptop">Radeon 移动端</string>
    <string name="amd_rWorkstation">Radeon 工作站端</string>
    <string name="amd_rEmbedded">Radeon 嵌入端</string>
    <string name="amd_fpDesktop">FirePro 工作站端</string>
    <string name="amd_fpLaptop">FirePro 移动工作站端</string>
    <string name="amd_fpServer">FirePro 服务器端</string>
    <string name="amd_fpMV">FirePro 多屏输出端</string>
    <string name="amd_fpRT">FirePro 远程端</string>
    <string name="amd_fStream">FireStream 流处理端</string>
    <!-- Categorias NVIDIA -->
    <string name="nvidia_gfDesktop">GeForce 桌面端</string>
    <string name="nvidia_gfLaptop">GeForce 移动端</string>
    <string name="nvidia_qDesktop">Quadro 工作站端</string>
    <string name="nvidia_qLaptop">Quadro 移动工作站端</string>
    <string name="nvidia_tDesktop">Tesla 超级计算端</string>
    <!-- Texto -->
    <string name="txtHome"><![CDATA[主页 >]]></string>
    <string name="txtCompare"><![CDATA[对比 >]]></string>
    <string name="txtSearchResult">结果</string>
    <string name="txtSearchNoResults">无结果</string>
    <string name="txtHelpTopGPU">这个列表包含近三十天内最热门的10个显卡（基于该APP使用者产生），并且每天都会更新。</string>
    <string name="txtHistory"><![CDATA[历史记录 >]]></string>
    <string name="txtHistoryEmpty">历史记录为空</string>
    <string name="txtHistoryDeleteOK">已从历史记录中删除</string>
    <string name="txtFavorites"><![CDATA[收藏 >]]></string>
    <string name="txtFavoritesEmpty">收藏夹为空</string>
    <string name="txtFavoriteAddOk">已经加入到收藏夹</string>
    <string name="txtFavoriteDeleteOK">已从收藏夹中移除</string>
    <string name="txtCopyClipboardOK">已经复制到剪贴板的说</string>
    <string name="txtVersion">版本</string>
    <string name="txtVariant">变体: </string>
    <string name="txtCancel">取消</string>
    <string name="txtClose">关闭</string>
    <string name="txtDelete">删除</string>
    <string name="txtSystemShared">系统分享</string>
    <string name="txtSystemDependent">系统依赖</string>
    <string name="txtShare">通过…分享</string>
    <string name="txtShareBody">下载CPU-L来获取最新的AN卡姿势！下载链接: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijsoft.cpul</string>
    <!-- Mensajes de Error -->
    <string name="errDeleteGpuHistory">在删除历史记录的时候发生了错误…</string>
    <string name="errInsertGpuFavorite">在加入收藏夹的时候发生了错误…</string>
    <string name="errDeleteGpuFavorite">在从收藏夹移除的时候发生了错误…</string>
    <string name="errGUI">在用户界面出现了未知错误的说…</string>
    <string name="errData">数据可能不见了呢…</string>
    <string name="errTopList">列表貌似消失了…</string>
    <string name="errGPUnotAvailable">您的软件已经过期了！请尽快更新！</string>
    <string name="errOpenURL">无法打开这个网址:</string>
    <!-- Dialogos -->
    <string name="diagDeleteGpuList">真的要把这个显卡移出列表吗?</string>
    <!-- Nombre Especificaciones -->
    <string name="gpu_name">名称</string>
    <string name="gpu_launch">发布时间</string>
    <string name="gpu_launch_price">发布价格</string>
    <string name="gpu_codename">代号名称</string>
    <string name="gpu_fab">制程</string>
    <string name="gpu_transistor">晶体管数（亿）</string>
    <string name="gpu_die">晶粒面积</string>
    <string name="gpu_bus">总线接口</string>
    <string name="gpu_coreclk">主频</string>
    <string name="gpu_coreboost">最高频率</string>
    <string name="gpu_shaderclk">着色器频率</string>
    <string name="gpu_sp">流处理器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_cuda">CUDA 核心数</string>
    <string name="gpu_eu">执行单元数</string>
    <string name="gpu_pixelshader">像素着色器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_vertexshader">顶点着色器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_textures">纹理贴图单元数</string>
    <string name="gpu_rops">光栅数</string>
    <string name="gpu_pxfiltrate">像素填充率</string>
    <string name="gpu_pxfiltrate_boost">像素填充率（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_txfiltrate">纹理填充率</string>
    <string name="gpu_txfiltrate_boost">纹理填充率（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_memoryType">显存种类</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorysize">显存大小</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorybus">显存总线宽度</string>
    <string name="gpu_memoryclk">显存频率</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorybw">显存带宽</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopssingle">单精度浮点数</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopssingle_boost">单精度浮点数（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopsdouble">双精度浮点数</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopsdouble_boost">双精度浮点数（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_notes">备注</string>
    <!-- Nombre Cortos Especificaciones -->
    <string name="gpu_launch_srt">发布日期</string>
    <string name="gpu_launch_price_srt">发布价格</string>
    <string name="gpu_codename_srt">代号名称</string>
    <string name="gpu_fab_srt">制程</string>
    <string name="gpu_transistor_srt">晶体管数（亿）</string>
    <string name="gpu_die_srt">晶粒面积</string>
    <string name="gpu_bus_srt">总线接口</string>
    <string name="gpu_coreclk_srt">主频</string>
    <string name="gpu_coreboost_srt">最高频率</string>
    <string name="gpu_shaderclk_srt">着色器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_sp_srt">流处理器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_pixelshader_srt">像素着色器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_vertexshader_srt">顶点着色器数</string>
    <string name="gpu_textures_srt">纹理贴图单元数</string>
    <string name="gpu_rops_srt">光栅数</string>
    <string name="gpu_pxfiltrate_srt">像素填充率</string>
    <string name="gpu_pxfiltrate_boost_srt">像素填充率（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_txfiltrate_srt">纹理填充率</string>
    <string name="gpu_txfiltrate_boost_srt">纹理填充率（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_memoryType_srt">类型</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorysize_srt">大小</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorybus_srt">总线宽度</string>
    <string name="gpu_memoryclk_srt">频率</string>
    <string name="gpu_memorybw_srt">带宽</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopssingle_srt">单</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopssingle_boost_srt">单（加速）</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopsdouble_srt">双</string>
    <string name="gpu_gflopsdouble_boost_srt">双（加速）</string>
    <!-- COMPARAR -->
    <string name="cmp_general">总体</string>
    <string name="cmp_core">核心</string>
    <string name="cmp_memory">显存</string>
    <string name="cmp_features">功能</string>
    <string name="cmp_fp">运算性能（精度浮点数）</string>
    <!-- MENU -->
    <string name="action_home">主页</string>
    <string name="action_top">当今趋势</string>
    <string name="action_help_top">这是什么?</string>
    <string name="action_favorites">收藏</string>
    <string name="action_history">显卡浏览记录</string>
    <string name="action_settings">设置</string>
    <string name="action_share">分享</string>
    <string name="action_about">关于我们</string>
    <string name="action_search">搜索</string>
    <string name="action_compare">对比</string>
    <string name="action_cpu_app">CPU-L</string>
    <string name="action_soc_app">SoC-L</string>
    <string name="action_select_gpu1">选择第一个显卡</string>
    <string name="action_select_gpu2">选择第二个显卡</string>
    <string name="action_add_favorite">加入收藏</string>
    <string name="action_copy_name">复制显卡名称</string>
    <string name="action_share_name">分享显卡名称</string>
    <!--Configuracion-->
    <string name="setting_listings">显卡列表</string>
    <string name="setting_listings_order">显卡列表排列方式</string>
    <string name="setting_listings_order_summary">决定显卡排列顺序（历史记录和收藏夹除外）</string>
    <string name="setting_toplist">当今趋势</string>
    <string name="setting_toplist_update">自动更新前十列表</string>
    <string name="setting_toplist_update_summary">是否自动更新最热门十大显卡</string>
</resources>
```

It is very strange but I do not know why the translation is not displayed when in my other application it is almost identical if it is displayed.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: try looking for help here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189875/simplified-and-traditional-chinese-vs-regions

Comment: I already saw it. The problem is that I have another app that if the translation is displayed and this is not.